# Preventing an app from retrieving iCloud data

Tags: ios, icloud, applications

I have an app that was previously downloaded on a different device but on the new device, I don't want that data, I just want to start from scratch. How can I prevent an app from retrieving that backed up iCloud data?

Comment: Which specific app are you talking about here? Are you logged in into iCloud with the same AppleID on both devices?

Comment: The app is land sliders and the same AppleID is on both devices

Comment: I still have not figured it out